# CodeIgniter - Why does library load fine in view but not in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using Stripe's php library. DL link: https://code.stripe.com/stripe-php-latest.zip

I've included the library like so inside of a view:
`require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/stripe/lib/stripe.php');`

Everything works fine when I do this in a view, but if I attempt to do it in a controller I get a server error. Why?

I have tried codeigniters load library method, but still a server error. I've change all capitals to lowercases, still the error.

Comment: hey kolby m also facing d same problem . Were u able to solve to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Loading Packages:

```
$this->load->add_package_path(APPPATH.'third_party/stripe/');
$this->load->library('stripe');
```

Documentation: Application "Packages" section

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html

Comment: Unable to load the requested class: stripe

Comment: You have too move lib files to application/third_party/stripe

Comment: Browse ci documentation page ;)

Comment: I have moved the library into the third party folder, and add_package_path isn't throwing an error, but when I try load library I get the error. I'm re-reading over the documentation now.

Comment: I browsed your stripe lib. Its a little complex. CI loads class but stripe library's including file not class.

Comment: What do you think is the best way to fix the problem? There is a codeigniter library I found on github, not much documentation so I'm not sure if I should use it. https://github.com/sekati/php-stripe Would it work better in this case?

Comment: github.com/sekati/php-stripe is provide your issue? If this solve your problem, you dont need load other. I think, use this that written for CI.

Comment: Haha I feel silly now, but the problem was because I named my controller stripe.php. Thanks for the help though; I didn't know about add_package_path, so at least I learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

If you use third_party libraries, like for example the Facebook PHP SDK, use the following code:

```
$this->_obj->load->add_package_path(APPPATH.'third_party/facebook/');
$this->_obj->load->library('facebook', $config);    
$this->_obj->load->remove_package_path(APPPATH.'third_party/facebook/');
```

And place the files for this library in the **/third_party/facebook/libraries/** folder.

Note: It's a common mistake to place the files directly in '/facebook/' instead of in '/libraries/' (and also not mentioned in the documentation, too bad).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stripe native library by adding as codeigniter helper.

step 1: put the stripe package into helper directory

step 2: rename the init.php to init_helper.php

step 3: load the helper into your controller

```
$this->load->helper('stripe/init');
```

step 4: call stripe library

```
try 
{
    // set api key
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('YOUR_SECRET_STRIPE_API_KEY');

    // create customer
    $customer_detail = \Stripe\customer::create(array(
                        'email'    => 'customer_email@testdomain.com'
                    ));

    echo $customer_detail->id;
}
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    $error = $e->getMessage();
    echo $error;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting your library on application/libraries and then load your librarie with
$this->load->libraries('Stripe.php');

Comment: The library file must be in capitalized (Stripe.php) but on library load you must write it in lowercase. $this->load->library('stripe'); Take a look to the Loader Class: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/loader.html

Comment: Keep in mind this is not a codeigniter library. I've included a dl link to it if you need to see. Stripe.php has no class but just includes several other classes that are separated into their own file.